# QCD quark self-energy, is the propagator momentum in the right direction?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, self-energy

For the quark self-energy diagram the amplitude is giving by:

[image]

The fermion propagator is given by $\frac{i}{\not p + l}$ in the lecture. It is not supposed to be $\frac{i}{\not p - l}$? It's seems that the gluon momentum is in the opposite direction of what the photon would have.

Comment: You're right, it's probably just a typo

Comment: Well, it doesnt really matter, since one integrates over gluon momentum anyway. Changing the direction of momenta on gluon lines does not affect their propagators and loop integrals with both p+l and p-l coincide.